# Image control URL setting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an image control .NET.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

How do I set the URL using code in C#, like

```
{
  this.Image1.   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
image1.ImageUrl = "~/Path/File.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

If using database , `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl = '<%#Eval("Field_db_of_image_path")%>' />`, assuming you are saving image path in db not actually image in db.